# Does GCP dataproc include webhcat?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I would like to know if GCP's DataProc supports [WebHCat](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat). [Googling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gcp%20dataproc%20webhcat&oq=gcp%20dataproc%20webhcat&aqs=chrome..69i57.7173j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) hasn't turned up anything.

So, does GCP DataProc support/provide WebHCat and if so what is the URL endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataproc does not provide WebHCat out of the box, however, its trivial to create an [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get install hive-webhcat-server
```

WebHCat will be available on port 50111:

http://my-cluster-m:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database/default/table/my-table

Alternatively, it is possible to setup a JDBC connection to HiveServer2 (available by default):
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can use [Dataproc Hive WebHCat component](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/hivewebhcat) to activate Hive WebHCat during cluster creation:

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME --optional-components=HIVE_WEBHCAT
```